# Using ansible k8s module: how to authenticate with certificates

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I'm struggling to deploy the playbook below (adding a namespace to Openshift 3.11 cluster):

```
---
- hosts: kubernetesmastergfm
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
   name_namespace: testingnamespace
  tasks:
   - name: Create a k8s namespace
     k8s:
      host: "https://{{ cluster.endpoint }}"
      ca_cert: "/etc/origin/master/ca.crt" <--WHERE IS THIS IN OPENSHIFT 3.11?
      api_key: "/etc/origin/master/admin.key"<--WHERE IS THIS IN OPENSHIFT 3.11?
      validate_certs: no
      name: pippo
      api_version: v1
      kind: Namespace
      state: present
```

I'm getting the error:

```
      ...
kubernetes.client.rest.ApiException: (401)
Reason: Unauthorized
HTTP response headers: HTTPHeaderDict({'Date': 'Tue, 16 Feb 2021 16:05:03 GMT', 'Content-Length': '129', 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Cache-Control': 'no-store'})
HTTP response body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}
```

I suspect that the certificates in the path below are wrong:
/etc/origin/master/ca.crt
/etc/origin/master/admin.key

Any suggestion is welcome.
Gian Filippo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `api_key` parameter is the value of the `ServiceAccount` token.
I think you should paste this token directly as a `api_key` parameter value becuse providing the path to the file with token doesn't seem to work.

I will describe required steps on a simple example to illustrate you how it works.

To find the token name associated with a specific `ServiceAccount` you can use:

```
###  kubectl describe sa <SERVICE ACCOUNT NAME> | grep "Token"

# kubectl describe sa namespace-creator | grep "Token"
Tokens:              namespace-creator-token-hs6zn
```

And then to display the value of this token:

```
### kubectl describe secret <TOKEN NAME> | grep "token:" 

# kubectl describe secret namespace-creator-token-hs6zn | grep "token:"
token:      ey(...)3Q
```

Finally pass this token value as  the `api_key` parameter value:

```
---
...
  tasks:
   - name: Create a k8s namespace
     community.kubernetes.k8s:
      ...
      api_key: "ey(...)3Q"
      validate_certs: no
      ...
```

To find out where the CA certificate is located, you may look at the `--client-ca-file` parameter of the API server e.g:

```
# kubectl describe pod kube-apiserver-master -n kube-system | grep "client-ca-file"
      --client-ca-file=/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.crt
```

**NOTE:** If you are using `validate_certs: no`,  you don't need to provide `ca_cert` parameter.

Additionally, if you want instead of [api_key](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/kubernetes/k8s_module.html#parameter-api_key), you can use [kubeconfig](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/kubernetes/k8s_module.html#parameter-kubeconfig) with path to an existing Kubernetes config file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out another way to authenticate to API (Openshift) by using **k8s_auth** rather then **k8s**.
The playbook should look like:

```
- hosts: localhost
  module_defaults:
    group/k8s:
      host: https://openshift-url:8443
      ca_cert: /etc/origin/master/ca.crt <<===THIS IS THE RIGHT PATH FOR OCP 3.11
  tasks:
     - name: Log in (obtain access token)
       k8s_auth:
          username: xxxx
          password: yyyy
       register: k8s_auth_results
```